# What can you do in ColdFusion in a single line?

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way of writing this logic in a single, elegant line of code?

```
<cfif ThumbnailWidth EQ 0>
   <cfset Width = 75>
<cfelse>
   <cfset Width = ThumbnailWidth>
</cfif>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? Single line != elegant.

Comment: That depends on whether you think concise == elegant. Opinions vary.

Comment: @anon, apparently you have not discovered the ternary operator that many languages support.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Coldfusion 9:

```
<!--- Syntax: ((condition) ? trueStatement : falseStatement) --->
<cfset width = ((ThumbnailWidth EQ 0) ? 75 : ThumbnailWidth) />
```

Coldfusion 8 and below:

```
<!--- Syntax: IIf(condition, trueStatement, falseStatement) --->
<cfset width = IIf((ThumbnailWidth EQ 0), 75, ThumbnailWidth) />
```

Some will say that [IIf()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/functions_h-im_05.html) is to be avoided for performance reasons. In this simple case I'm sure you'll find no difference. Ben Nadel's Blog has [more discussion on IIF() performance](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/162-ColdFusion-IIF-vs-CFIF.htm) and [the new ternary operator in CF 9](http://www.bennadel.com/index.cfm?dax=blog:1643.view).

Comment: Does anyone with CF9 know whether I can use == rather than EQ in the CF9 version? I'm guessing it's still CF best practice to use EQ since it's backwards compatible, but wouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: In actual practice, for code maintainability, I'd replace the hard coded 75 with a variable that can be set in a config file.

Comment: Yes, you may use ==, but some operators that has '>' or '<' should only be used in CFScript.

Answer (score 6):

I find your original elegant enough - tells the story, easy to read.  But that's definitely a personal preference.  Luckily there's always at least nine ways to do anything in CFML.

You can put that on one line (CFML has no end-of-line requirements):

```
<cfif ThumbnailWidth EQ 0><cfset Width = 75><cfelse><cfset Width = ThumbnailWidth></cfif>
```

You can also use [IIF() Function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/6/CFML_Reference/functions-pt1117.htm) - it'll do the trick:

```
<cfset Width = IIf(ThumbnailWidth EQ 0, 75, ThumbnailWidth)>
```

This construct is a little odd tho' -  is more clear I think.  The strength of IIF() is that it can also be used inline (it is a function after all).  For example:

```
<img src="#ImageName#" width="#IIf(ThumbnailWidth EQ 0, 75, ThumbnailWidth)#">
```

This last form is often used to maintain a clean(er) HTML layout while injecting dynamic code.

Comment: I believe that `IIf()` requires the use of `DE()`.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think it's required in this case since we're passing integers rather than strings. (source: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_37.html)

Comment: Exactly - DE() is "Delay Evaluation" - and it's probably the most confusing part of using IIF().  By default each clause of IIF() is evaluated (as if in the Evaluate() function).  If that's NOT what you want you have to use DE() - but in this case these are simple expressions so it doesn't matter.  It won't hurt to use it - but it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Like Neil said, it's fine the way it is. If you really want a single line you could make it a `cfscript` with a ternary operator, like:

```
<cfscript>width = (ThumbnailWidth == 0) ? 75 : ThumbnailWidth;</cfscript>
```

Haven't tested this code, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for concise code, then you can take it a step further than the other examples, taking advantage of CF's evaluation of non-zero values as `true`:

```
<!--- CF 9 example --->
<cfset width = ThumbnailWidth ? ThumbnailWidth : 75> 

<!--- CF 8 and below --->
<cfset width = iif(ThumbnailWidth, ThumbnailWidth, 0)>
```

Naturally, you'll sacrifice a little clarity, but that's the tradeoff for more compact code.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer something more along the lines of this:

```
<cfscript>
  Width = ThumbnailWidth;
  if(NOT Val(Width)) // if the Width is zero, reset it to the default width.
    Width = 75;
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the you are submitting the ThumbnailWidth variable through form submission of either a get or post method, it could look like this if using LUCEE 5 or greater:

```
//POST
width = form.ThumbnailWidth ?: 0;
//GET
width = url.ThumbnailWidth ?: 0;
```

The default value is 0, while the form and url scope contain the client request.